# How to "break line" via CSS?

Tags: html, css

Let's suppose that I have a HTML page that renders something like bellow:

```
labelA [___INPUT-TEXT____] labelB [___INPUT-TEXT____]
```

However, I want to "break the line" on the second label, something like:

```
labelA [___INPUT-TEXT____]
labelB [___INPUT-TEXT____]
```

Assuming that I can not change the HTML code. How can I do it with CSS?

Here is an example:

```
<html><head><style>
#labelA { display:block; }
#labelB { display:block; }
</style></head>
<body>
<label for="ia" id="labelA">labelA</label><input id="ia" type="text"/>
<label for="ib" id="labelB">labelB</label><input id="ib" type="text"/>
</body></html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers,

---

EDIT:
I mean  `{ display: block; }` instead of `{inline:block}`, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: `display: block` should fix this, assuming you don't have it floated.

Comment: @brad, I was thinking the same thing, and `clear: left` would fix `float`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `display: block;` instead of `inline: block;` and I think it should do what you want.

**EDIT** Didn't read your question carefully enough. If you want to group the label and text input together on a line, you can use something like:

```
label, input {
    float: left;
}

label {
    clear: left;
}
```

...and here's [a more polished jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdWRV/1/) demonstration courtesy of Tim Medora

Comment: +1 - Here's a version of that which spaces the elements and vertically aligns the text: http://jsfiddle.net/bdWRV/1/

Comment: I tried all the answers in this post and this one seems to be the best option in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a non-obvious way if you can use `:before`:

```
#labelB:before {
    white-space: pre;
    content: '\A';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/9AkMu/

Comment: interesting! would you please provide description of content: '/A'; any website.

Comment: `\A` is a just a `newline` character that works in CSS (where `\n` would not).

Comment: \n is "new line" and what is \a meaning ?

Comment: could we apply like this : #someid /A{somestyle;} that I could give style to after a line.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming that I can not change the HTML code. How can I do it with
>   CSS?

The easy way to do it would be to just wrap each label/input pair in a `div` (or other block element, or element styled as a block element). However, if you can't change the HTML...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bdWRV/

```
#labelB:before{ content: ""; display: block; }
```

This works in Chrome 25, Firefox, and IE 9/10. In my opinion, it's sort of a hack. At best, it's not ideal.

Comment: Thanks Tim, this is a handy option. However, in my particular case float seems to be a better option because is has better compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You have placed wrong statement `inline: block;` this should be `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;` like this `display` should be defined. I think you need to learn css more then go to w3school or search for css tutorial in google or perhaps may be you have placed `inline: block;` mistakenly. For your question, you need to define `display: block;` is okay as other answers.

Comment: Right, I mistakenly placed "inline:block" [Yes, I need to learn more CSS, I am a back-end developer afterall :) ]. I've tried several combinations as you suggested, but could not achieve my goal... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just simple use `<br />` but in your case, just simple used `float` using float is not guarantee unless you use `100%` width in your element

below example using `<br />`

```
<label for="ia" id="labelA">labelA</label><input id="ia" type="text"/><br />
<label for="ib" id="labelB">labelB</label><input id="ib" type="text"/>
```

using float;

```
float:left;
width:100%;
```